# How to create program startup parameters in python

Tags: python, parameters, startup, pydev

I'm just beginning to learn python and the program I'm writing requires parameters for it to run with a specific task. For example (programs name is Samtho)

```
samtho -i Mozilla_Firefox
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the documentation on [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html). It is very powerful and will let you lots of parameters and create the help text.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the modules [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/optparse.html) and [`getopt`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getopt.html) from the standard library. The former is more flexible and thus recommended.

If you want to write your own parser, then you'll have to inspect the contents of `sys.argv`. `sys.argv[0]` contains the name of the program being executed. `sys.argv[1:]` is a list containing all arguments passed to the program.

This is a minimal example using `optparse` (I mimicked program execution by manually setting `sys.argv`):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv = 'samtho -i Mozilla_Firefox'.split()
>>>
>>> from optparse import OptionParser
>>> parser = OptionParser()
>>> parser.add_option("-i")
<Option at 0xb7881b4c: -i>
>>> options, args = parser.parse_args()
>>> options
<Values at 0xb788958c: {'i': 'Mozilla_Firefox'}>
>>> options.i
'Mozilla_Firefox'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sys.argv` to grab input arguments directly (`import sys` first).  There are a bunch of different libraries (`optparse` and `getopt` builtin modules are popular) to help parse the arguments but doing raw matching might be easier depending on what complexity you need.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind venturing from the standard library, [argparse](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/) is generally considered best-in-breed for parameter parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I find [optfunc](http://github.com/simonw/optfunc) the easiest library to use.

```
import optfunc, sys

def samtho(i=''):
    "Usage: %prog -i <option>"
    print i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    optfunc.run(samtho)
```